# Hover over the paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to create a paragraph on which if a user hovers the mouse, it should display an alert box. But the code that I typed did not work. As soon as the mouse entered the *page* the box displayed. I only want it to display when the mouse is on the *paragraph*. The code was :

```
<html>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#p1').hover(
        alert("you have entered p1 .")
    );
});
</script>
<body>
    <p id="p1">hover here!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what JS error did you get?

Comment: Correction at line 5 it will be `$('#p1')` #denotes `id`

Comment: There was no error , the popup was not coming on the right time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htmled/caVay/).

Try this:

```
$('#p1').hover(
    alert("you have entered p1 .");
);
```

or:

```
$('#p1').hover(
    function() {
        alert("you have entered p1 .");
    },
    function() {
        alert('you have exited p1 .');
    }
);
```

Comment: Because there no function passed to hover(), rather you're passing the return value of alert(if there is any)!

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('#p1').hover(function(){
       alert("you have entered p1 .")
   });
});
</script>
<body>
<p id="p1">hover here!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

You forgot the #

Comment: but still the popup does not appears when the mouse is hovering on the paragraph .

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#p1').hover(
        alert("you have entered p1 .")
    );
});
</script>
<body>
<p id="p1">hover here!!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your script:

1. 'document' the quotes not to be there
2. missing function in hover

so it should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // <----removed the quotes
   $('#p1').hover(function(){ //<------added the function here.
      alert("you have entered p1 .")
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

//try this 1 dude...

```
$("#p1").hover(
function () {
   alert("you have entered p1 .")
},
function () {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="p1">hover here!!</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#p1').mouseover(function() {
  alert("you have entered p1 .");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want hover effect for all the paragraphs in your page,then go for this

```
$('p').hover(function1(),function2());
```

(or)
if you want hover effect for particular paragraph,then

```
$('#ID_OF_YOUR_PARAGRAPH').hover(function1(),function2());
```